# Beta testing application in Android not available to some testers

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing

I have created a beta testing application with "Open Beta Testing" attribute, which means that anyone with a proper link could become my tester. How ever i have encountered a weird issue.

Some of the testers get the following screen in the play-store after opening the tetsers's link :

[image]

As you can see **there is no Install button available** like it should be:

[image]

Can anyone explain if im doing something wrong ? 
Is it a google's issue ?
How can i make the app more accessible?

Comment: do your testers have Developers accounts?

Comment: did they click on "Leave the test" button?

Comment: @D.'s some have, some havent. but most of them are regular users. and some of them get the right screen and other dont

Comment: @SomeshKumar  no they didn't, otherwise i wouldn't ask :)

Comment: well do me a little favor please check if those who have the dev account are the one who cant install

Comment: @D.'s this is not the case. i have my private dev account and i was able to install.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is users who were already in a closed beta, or on an Alpha channel who aren't getting the update link. Or maybe users who already had the app installed to some more recent version?

Comment: I have thought of this case already. Some of my co-workers had the official version of the the app and after uninstalling, they were able to install the beta version. **But** only some of them.